# Break Python list item down into smaller list, replace new sub list item, and put list back together with new value

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to do this, so apologies for any confusion.

I would like to take a list containing sentences, and break the sentences down into a smaller sub list.

Somehow, I was hoping to replace an item in new sub list, and return the list back with it's new value.

For example:

```
txt_lst = ['That is Jays sock.', 'It is green.', 'Leave it there.']
```

Then I want to take `txt_lst[0]`, and make a new sub_txt_lst:

```
sub_txt_lst = ['That', 'is', 'Jays', 'sock.']
```

And replace the item `sub_txt_lst[2]` with `her`.

Afterwards, I would like `txt_lst` to read:

```
txt_lst = ['That is her sock.', 'It is green.', 'Leave it there.']
```

Again, sorry if this explanation is poorly written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to do this in an efficient way:

```
import re

txt_lst = ['That is Jays sock.', 'It is green.', 'Leave it there.']
print([re.sub(r'\bJays\b', 'her', x) for x in txt_lst])

# ['That is her sock.', 'It is green.', 'Leave it there.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
txt_lst = ['That is Jays sock.', 'It is green.', 'Leave it there.']
sub_txt_lst = txt_lst[0].split()
sub_txt_lst[2] = "her"
txt_lst[0] =  " ".join(sub_txt_lst)
```

Or if you'd like to just modify a specific word:

```
txt_lst[0] = txt_lst[0].replace("Jays","her")
```

Both yield:

```
['That is her sock.', 'It is green.', 'Leave it there.']
```

Comment: The problem with second approach is it doesn't always replace words; but anything that it matches.